# Issues compiling C++ 11 code from a remote host

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, std

I'm trying to compile C++ 11 code on a server running Ubuntu from my home computer using Putty. I'm using a makefile to compile and include shared pointers in the code, but it gives me this error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
```

However, when I try to compile the code from the server hosting the files (when I'm at university), it compiles perfectly. Here is my makefile:

```
all: huffmandriver.o huffmannode.o huffmantree.o
    g++ -o huffencode huffmandriver.o huffmannode.o huffmantree.o -std=c++11

huffmannode.o: huffmannode.cpp huffmannode.h
    g++ -c huffmannode.cpp -std=c++11

huffmantree.o: huffmantree.cpp huffmantree.h
    g++ -c huffmantree.cpp -std=c++11

clean:
    @rm -f *.o
    @rm -f huffencode
```

I have also tried adding the flags `-stdlib=libc++ -std=gnu++`, but that does not work either. Here is a snippet of the code where the error is being thrown:

```
// Huffman Node class header

#ifndef HUFFMANNODE_H
#define HUFFMANNODE_H

#include <memory>
#include <string>

namespace YNGMAT005 {

class HuffmanNode {
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<HuffmanNode> left;
        std::shared_ptr<HuffmanNode> right;
        std::shared_ptr<HuffmanNode> parent;
        std::string letter;
        int frequency;

    public:
        HuffmanNode(std::string l, int freq);
        ~HuffmanNode();
        std::shared_ptr<HuffmanNode> & get_left();
        std::shared_ptr<HuffmanNode> & get_right();
        std::shared_ptr<HuffmanNode> & get_parent();
        void set_left(std::shared_ptr<HuffmanNode> & l);
        void set_right(std::shared_ptr<HuffmanNode> & r);
        bool has_left();
        bool has_right();
        void set_parent(std::shared_ptr<HuffmanNode> & p);
        bool has_parent();
        std::string get_letter();
        int get_frequency();
    };

}

#endif
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Can't you just run 'which g++' and 'g++ --version' in both cases to see which compiler you are using (I'm assuming g++)?

Comment: The server is using g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4, and "which g++" returns "/usr/bin/g++".

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you're seeing different behaviour from a different login context (check `which g++; g++ --version` on both and see if your `.profile`, `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` does anything weird based on ssh-vs-local login).

Nonetheless, you should be able to getting it working in both settings by providing `-std=c++11` to the default rule for .cpp to .o thus:

```
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11
```

Additionally, (shamelessly stealing from Daniel's answer) you can remove the explicit rules for the other .cpp files, just leaving the .h dependencies:

```
huffmannode.o: huffmannode.h

huffmantree.o: huffmantree.h
```

These will then automatically pick up the CXXFLAGS setting.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to compile `huffmandriver.cpp` with `-std=c++11` as well. Currently, you have rules for compiling `huffmannode.cpp` and `huffmantree.cpp` with the `-std=c++11` compiler option, but not `huffmandriver.cpp`.

You can create a custom [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html#Pattern-Rules) for making `.o` files from `.cpp` files and specifying the header dependencies like so:

```
huffmannode.o: huffmannode.h

huffmantree.o: huffmantree.h

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -c -march=native -o $@ $<
```

An alternative approach is to define the [`CXXFLAGS` implicit variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html) to `-std=c++11`. This way, the [built-in rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html) ‘`$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c`’ for compiling C++ source files will use the `-std=c++11` compiler option.